# Converting Numbers to Letters of the Alphabet in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to convert numbers from a spin edit to a letter of the alphabet. Here is what I have so far:

```
procedure TForm2.btnRepeatClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iNumLetters, iCounter, i: Integer;
begin
  iNumLetters := sedNum.Value;
  iCounter := 0;
  repeat
    redOut.Lines.Add(Chr(iCounter));
    Inc(iCounter);
  until (iCounter = iNumLetters);   
end;
```

Right now I am getting an error

> Rich edit line insertion error

Comment: What do you mean by "alphabet"? If you mean A, B, C, etc., then you clearly won't get that: you start with `Chr(0)`, which is not A. If you mean #0, #1, #2, etc., then things get tricky. The two possibilities require different approaches to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sedNum.Value` doesn't exceed 26, you can do something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.btnRepeatClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iNumLetters, iCounter: Integer;
begin
  iNumLetters := sedNum.Value;
  for iCounter := 0 to iNumLetters-1 do
    redOut.Lines.Add(Char(Ord('A') + iCounter));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Chr` converts an integer value into the character with that ordinal value, using the prevailing character encoding. That's not what you want. The letter `A` is not encoded with ordinal value 0.

You want to convert 0 into A, 1 into B and so on. Instead of `Chr(iCounter)` you want `Chr(iCounter + ord('A'))`. Note that this relies on the letters being encoded as ordinal values in the same order as the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
function TForm2.numberToString(number: Integer): String;
begin
    Result := '';
    if (number < 1) or (number > 26) then
        Exit;

    Result := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[number];
end;
```